# Codewars find the perfect square

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I know this is cheating, but I want to know the answer.

I have to write a function that takes an odd integer which is the difference between two consecutive perfect squares and find the squares.

now, my problem is the number of perfect squares must reach up to 1,000,000

and the system won't accept if it takes more than 12ms to finish executing the code.

what is the right way to re-write the code so it can pass the test?

```
   function findSquare(input)
        {
        
        let perfectSquare = []
        let output
        
            for(let i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++){
                
                perfectSquare = [...perfectSquare, i*i]
            }
            
           for(let x = 0; x < perfectSquare.length; x++){

               if(perfectSquare[x+1] - perfectSquare[x] === input){

                   output = `${perfectSquare[x+1]}-${perfectSquare[x]}`

                   break
               }
           }

            return output
            
        }

        findSquare(9)
```

the output would be "25-16"

Comment: Is the question from a live contest?

Comment: nope, just from regular kata

Comment: The difference between consecutive perfect squares is quite simple to derive. You can calculate the answer directly with no searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the two numbers be `a` and `b` such that `b = a + 1` and now according to the question we have to find such a `x` such that `b * b - a * a = x`.

We have

```
(b * b) - (a * a) = x

but b = a + 1, so replace b by a + 1

((a + 1) * (a + 1)) - (a * a) = x

Now we know that (A + B) * (A + B) = (A * A) + (2 * A * B) + (B * B)

((a + 1) * (a + 1)) - (a * a) = x

((a * a) + (2 * a * 1) + (1 * 1)) - (a * a) = x

(2 * a) + 1 = x

2a + 1 = x

a = (x - 1) / 2;  (x is odd (as mentiond in problem), so a is an integer

and b can be found as b = a + 1
```

So our required answer will be `(b * b), (a * a)`

```js
function solve(x) {
  let a = (x - 1) / 2;
  let b = a + 1;
  console.log(b * b, a * a)
}

solve(9);
```